# 'Context' is an ambiguous reference between 'Filename.Models.Context' and 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensiblity.Implementation.Context'"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

As I'm Using ASP.Net Core MVC 5 for developing an login page. While I'm Connecting with SQL server(LocalDb) in Startup.cs I'm Getting this error.
 "'Context' is an ambiguous reference between 'Filename.Models.Context' and 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensiblity.Implementation.Context'"

Comment: Well just use full namespace instead, so it is not ambiguous anymore.

Comment: According to your Exception Message, Use Full Name space of your context class you want to use.

Comment: Can you please explain with an example.? I can't able to understand.

Comment: Yes, I used my full name space only.Still this error occuring.

Comment: Maybe you just have to review the using list at the top of your source. And remove those that are not necessary.

Comment: @PepitoSh As you said I had removed the unnecessary using list,Still no change there.

Comment: If your `Context` is supposed to be the one from `Filename.Models` then write `Filename.Models.Context` instead of `Context`. If not, then write `Miscrosoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.Context` instead of `Context`. This is what using *full namespace* is.

Comment: I think you should understand WHY the error message is thrown. Then you will understand Rafalon's solution.

Comment: Ho.! It's working @Rafalon. Thank you, Thank you all..

Comment: The error was there because the system couldn't figure out which `Context` class you were talking about. Using full namespace removes ambiguousness: *I want to use **this class**!*